# jQuery excluding document.ready event for a specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have the below code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".rightImage").last().append("<iframe src='http://images.findel-     education.co.uk/EmailSignup/website_email_sign_up.html' width='180px'frameborder='0' height='250px'></iframe>");  
});
```

The above code adds an iframe to a class, the problem is it appears on every page. Is there a way to filter out the above function to work on every page except my homepage?
 I don't have control of the parent's html so that's why I have to do it this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.location` try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location !== "homepageurl"){
        $(".rightImage").last().append("<iframe src='http://images.findel-education.co.uk/EmailSignup/website_email_sign_up.html' width='180px'frameborder='0' height='250px'></iframe>");  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.location.href != 'homepage_url') {
        $(".rightImage").last().append("<iframe src='http://images.findel-     education.co.uk/EmailSignup/website_email_sign_up.html' width='180px'frameborder='0' height='250px'></iframe>"); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

check the `window.location` and execute the steps in the document.ready if its not a match

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.location != "exceptionURL") {

          $(".rightImage").last().append("<iframe src='http://images.findel-     education.co.uk/EmailSignup/website_email_sign_up.html' width='180px'frameborder='0' height='250px'></iframe>");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

add a filter with the url

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      if(window.location.href!='http://yourhomepage'){
           $(".rightImage").last().append("<iframe src='http://images.findel-     education.co.uk/EmailSignup/website_email_sign_up.html' width='180px'frameborder='0' height='250px'></iframe>");  
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the url:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf('http://www.example.com') != 0) {
        $(".rightImage").last().append("<iframe src='http://images.findel-     education.co.uk/EmailSignup/website_email_sign_up.html' width='180px'frameborder='0' height='250px'></iframe>");  
    }
});
```

If the current url starts with 'http://www.example.com' it wont execute the following code, else it will append the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(function(){
    if(!location.pathName.contains('home')){ 
        $(".rightImage").last().append("<iframe .... height='250px'></iframe>");
    }
});
```

check if related a specific word about your home page is available in the url.